# What is the right way to avoid using raw type Comparable in a sort algorithm?

Tags: java, raw-types

I am writing a merge sort algorithms, so I want all the methods take arguments that implements `Comparable` interface, i.e. having a method called `compareTo`.

I have been told many times to avoid using ***raw type*** in new code. But I can't find a right way to replace them.

```
public class Merge{
    private static Comparable[] aux;
    private Merge() {}

    private static boolean less(Comparable v,Comparable w){
        int sign=v.compareTo(w);
        if (sign==0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Repeated points");
        return sign<0;
    }


    private static void exch(Comparable[] a,int i,int j){
        Comparable swap =a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=swap;
    }

    private static void insertSort(Comparable[] a,int lo,int hi){

        for(int i=lo;i<hi+1;++i){
            for(int j=i;j>lo;--j){
                if(less(a[j],a[j-1]))
                    exch(a,j,j-1);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void merge(Comparable[] a,Comparable[] aux,int lo,int mid,int hi){
        for(int k=lo;k!=hi+1;++k){
            aux[k]=a[k];
        }

        int i=lo,j=mid+1;
        for(int k=lo;k!=hi+1;++k){
            if(i>mid){
                a[k]=aux[j++];
            }
            else if(j>hi){
                a[k]=aux[i++];
            }
            else if(less(aux[j],aux[i])){
                a[k]=aux[j++];
            }
            else{
                a[k]=aux[i++];
            }
        }
    }


    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux,int lo,int hi){
        if(hi<=lo+6){
            insertSort(a,lo,hi);
            return;
        }
        int mid=lo+ (hi-lo)/2;
        sort(a,aux,lo,mid);
        sort(a,aux,mid+1,hi);
        if(!less(a[mid+1],a[mid])) return;
        merge(a,aux,lo,mid,hi);
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] a){
        aux=new Comparable[a.length];
        sort(a,aux,0,a.length-1);
    }     

}
```

The question [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) is different from mine. Actually, I have read the question before. Still, I don't know how toa avoid using `Comparable` here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @JoeC No, I ask for how to not use raw type here instead why shouldn't use it.

Comment: And this question is answered there as well.

Comment: @JoeC Sorry, I can't find one, if there, can you point out which asnwer can solve my problem?

Comment: **1.** You are using arrays, but it's possibly better to use `List`s, because they are more flexible. **2.** You should definitely use braces while using if, else or for statements. Doing so would save you work *and* nasty bugs in the future. **3.** You should rethink of the design. You have a lot of static methods, as well as static fields, and you are passing around `aux` a lot. It's possibly better to make the methods and fields non-static and operate on the `Merge` object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereever you have `Comparable`, use `T`. And declare `T` as `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

You will face a problem with array creation, though. There are two ways how to bypass that. You could clone the original array and clear it in case you need it to be initialized with `null`, or you could use Reflection to create the array.

```
public class Merge {
    private Merge() {
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean less(T v, T w) {
        int sign = v.compareTo(w);
        if (sign == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Repeated points");
        return sign < 0;
    }


    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void exch(T[] a, int i, int j) {
        T swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertSort(T[] a, int lo, int hi) {

        for (int i = lo; i < hi + 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j > lo; --j) {
                if (less(a[j], a[j - 1]))
                    exch(a, j, j - 1);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(T[] a, T[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        for (int k = lo; k != hi + 1; ++k) {
            aux[k] = a[k];
        }

        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k != hi + 1; ++k) {
            if (i > mid) {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            } else if (j > hi) {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            } else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            } else {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }
    }


    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a, T[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
        if (hi <= lo + 6) {
            insertSort(a, lo, hi);
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        if (!less(a[mid + 1], a[mid])) return;
        merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a) {
        T[] aux = a.clone();
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

}
```

You can do away with the repetition of the type parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` and also the repetition of `a` and `aux` if you use a method object.

```
public enum Merge {
    ;

    private static class Merger<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
        private final T[] a;
        private final T[] aux;

        private Merger(T[] a) {
            this.a = a;
            aux = a.clone();
        }
        private boolean less(T v, T w) {
            int sign = v.compareTo(w);
            if (sign == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Repeated points");
            return sign < 0;
        }

        private void exch(int i, int j) {
            T swap = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = swap;
        }

        private void insertSort(int lo, int hi) {

            for (int i = lo; i < hi + 1; ++i) {
                for (int j = i; j > lo; --j) {
                    if (less(a[j], a[j - 1]))
                        exch(j, j - 1);
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void merge(int lo, int mid, int hi) {
            for (int k = lo; k != hi + 1; ++k) {
                aux[k] = a[k];
            }

            int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
            for (int k = lo; k != hi + 1; ++k) {
                if (i > mid) {
                    a[k] = aux[j++];
                } else if (j > hi) {
                    a[k] = aux[i++];
                } else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) {
                    a[k] = aux[j++];
                } else {
                    a[k] = aux[i++];
                }
            }
        }


        private void sort(int lo, int hi) {
            if (hi <= lo + 6) {
                insertSort(lo, hi);
                return;
            }
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            sort(lo, mid);
            sort(mid + 1, hi);
            if (!less(a[mid + 1], a[mid])) return;
                merge(lo, mid, hi);
        }
        private void sort() {
            sort(0, a.length - 1);
        }
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a) {
        new Merger<>(a).sort();
    }

}
```

Comment: Must I add  <T extends Comparable<? super T>> in front of each method? Is there anyway to write <T extends Comparable<? super T>> once ?

Comment: @K.Robert, since these are static methods, you need the generic type for each one

Comment: You could avoid that by creating a method object. In the method that shuold be public, which is `sort(T[] a)`, create an instance of `Merge` which holds `aux` and has all other methods as instance methods. Then you can declare the type parameter on class Merge. That would also be useful to avoid passing around aux everywhere. I would then, however, split this into two classes, one which implements the actual algorithm and has the temporary array and the type parameter, and another one that looks as simple as possible to the user.

Comment: @ChristianHujer one more question, Why can't create an Object [] and cast it to T[] before assigning to aux here?

Comment: @K.Robert At runtime, that will throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException`. `Object[]` is a different type than `String[]`, and `Object[]` cannot be cast to `String[]` if it's not really a `String[]`. See, an Array knows its component type, and this component type is part of the type check. This type check not only happens when updating the array, it also happens when assigning the array. It has to. Imagine `String[] s = (String[]) new Object[1];` would work. As a consequence of that, `((Object[])s)[0] = new Object();` would work, and now `s[0]` would not be a `String`.

Comment: @ChristianHujer thx, I find a way to avoid the time-consuming array copy by replacing `aux=a.clone()` by `aux=new Comparable<?>[a.length]`. Since  type `T` is lowerbound to type `Comparable`.

Comment: That works in your case because aux is temporary. If it were a copy-on-write implementation, taking the input immutable and returning a new array, `new Comparable<?>[a.length]` would not be an option.